# INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE row IF date_added > VALUES(date_added)

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates, insert-update

How can I `INSERT` and `ON DUPLICATE KEY` update the whole row if a certain condition is met? 
I want to update the whole `row` if `VALUES(date_added)` is older then `date_added` from the table.

I've seen this article:

https://thewebfellas.com/blog/conditional-duplicate-key-updates-with-mysql

```
INSERT INTO daily_events
  (created_on, last_event_id, last_event_created_at)
VALUES
  ('2010-01-19', 23, '2010-01-19 10:23:11')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  last_event_id = IF(last_event_created_at < VALUES(last_event_created_at), VALUES(last_event_id), last_event_id),
  last_event_created_at = IF(last_event_created_at < VALUES(last_event_created_at), VALUES(last_event_created_at), last_event_created_at);
```

But this isn't a flexible way to write the statement.

Later Edit:

First, because the condition is evaluated for each field that will be updated, and second, because you have to pay attention to position the line that updates the condition column, in the last position of the statement. Otherwise you poison the `UPDATE` with errors.

To be more exact, I'd want this statement, where I've inverted the two UPDATE lines, to be valid also:

`INSERT INTO daily_events(created_on, last_event_id, last_event_created_at) VALUES('2010-01-19', 23, '2010-01-19 10:23:11') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    last_event_created_at = GREATEST(last_event_created_at,      VALUES(last_event_created_at)), 
    last_event_id = (CASE WHEN last_event_created_at < VALUES(last_event_created_at) THEN VALUES(last_event_id) ELSE last_event_id END);`

This isn't possible because:

> An important thing to keep in mind when using this approach is that the order in which you update your fields is very important. I was wrongly under the impression that the updates took place in one mass-assignment after the entire query had been interpreted by MySQL. But they’re not: the assignments happen in the order they appear in the query.
>
> When the `update` is executed with a more recent event, the `last_event_created_at` field will be updated, but the `last_event_id` field won’t. This is because when the second `IF` is evaluated `last_event_created_at` has already been updated so that `last_event_created_at` is equal to `VALUES(last_event_created_at)`. Crazy huh?!

Comment: I am confused by your question.  Your query seems to do what you want it to do.

Comment: I don't want to evaluate the condition twice, because I cannot control the order of the columns. And from that example, you can see that the last column that has to be updated is the one that has the condition on it. Otherwise you would poison the table with incorrect values.

Comment: Who gave the "-1"? It's useless to downvote without explanation. You're not preventing me from doing the mistake that you consider, again, in the future.

Comment: The article gave you some alternatives. I am still not sure what you are trying to achieve, since you could just use one of the working ones. If you don't like the current syntax, you can try to convince the mysql developers to e.g. implement sql standard `merge`, which would probably do what you want (test first, then update or not). `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` works the way it does. If you want more flexibility than you can use seperate statements. This will look a lot cleaner in perl than anything you could do with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` with repeated conditions (and is more standard sql).

Comment: Btw, good edit, I upvoted you to get you back to 0, because now your question/problem is a lot clearer (although I still don't know why it is a problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query seems to do what you want, so I don't fully understand the question.  You might simplify it by using `GREATEST()`:

```
INSERT INTO daily_events(created_on, last_event_id, last_event_created_at)
    VALUES('2010-01-19', 23, '2010-01-19 10:23:11')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  last_event_id = (CASE WHEN last_event_created_at < VALUES(last_event_created_at) THEN VALUES(last_event_id) ELSE last_event_id END),
  last_event_created_at = GREATEST(last_event_created_at, VALUES(last_event_created_at));
```

(The use of `CASE` is a preference for ANSI standards for equivalent functionality.)

MySQL doesn't offer a way to say "update all of these when this condition is met".

Comment: I want to get rid off the requirement to keep the column that has the condition on it at last( in this case, the `date_added` column). I will use this statement in Perl, and writing code to detect a certain column and put it on the last line of the statement, would make the Perl code look ugly, long, inefficient, etc.

Comment: To be more exact, I'd want this statement, where I've inverted the two `UPDATE` lines, to be valid also: `INSERT INTO daily_events(created_on, last_event_id, last_event_created_at)
    VALUES('2010-01-19', 23, '2010-01-19 10:23:11')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  last_event_created_at = GREATEST(last_event_created_at, VALUES(last_event_created_at)),
  last_event_id = (CASE WHEN last_event_created_at < VALUES(last_event_created_at) THEN VALUES(last_event_id) ELSE last_event_id END);`